# stuck with php submit response

Tags: php, html, forms, response

I cant figure out whats wrong with the code.
The problem occurs when i try to send form data to email.
So far its good but i cant get response code to work.
I mean when i fill form and click send it wont show predefined error when some of the forms are empty or when it was sent. Response should be in a same window or form.

Code i have at the moment:

```html
<form name="action" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<?php if( isset($error_msg) && $error_msg != '' ) { echo $error_msg; } ?>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ees-ja perekonnanimi">

<input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" placeholder="Ettevõtte nimi" style="width: 55%;"> <input type="text" name="regnum" id="regnum" placeholder="Reg. number" style="width: 25%;">

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-post">
<textarea name="info" placeholder="Sõnum" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Esita" onclick="return getData()">
<div id="error_msg"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></div>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
 $cname=$_REQUEST['cname'];
 $regnum=$_REQUEST['regnum'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
 $info=$_REQUEST['info'];
    if (($name=="")||($email==""))
        {
  $error_msg="All fields are required";
     }
    else{
  $data="Kliendi nimi: $name \r\nEttevõtte nimi: $cname \r\nEttevõtte reg. number: $regnum \r\nE-post: $email \r\nSõnum: $info";
        $subject="Tellimus";
  mail("someone@somewhere.com", $subject, $data);
  $error_msg="Your message was sent, Thank you!";
     }
    }
 }
?>
</form>
```

any advice?

Comment: You're defining `$error_msg` _after_ you're trying to print it. PHP is parsed from top to bottom. Move your PHP-code to the top of the page, before any HTML is outputted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, im pretty new to php ^-^

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.